# Firefox Sync Preferences also syncs its own settings, bug or by design?

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I have 4 firefox installs. On two I want Add-ons synced. On two I want separate addons.

However, whenever Preferences is set to sync, the Sync settings are synced. It's very confusing.
i.e. - Once sync Preferences is checked, all Sync settings are the same across installs. There's no way to have any of the other Sync settings different without also unchecking Preferences.

Hopefully that makes sense...
[image: Firefox Sync Settings]

Is this a bug or by design?
It seems the Sync settings should be independent for each Firefox install.

Answer (score 0):

I sync only Bookmarks and Passwords. I do not sync Preferences. When I log into sync with a fresh Firefox profile, it automatically selects Bookmarks and Passwords in the sync settings.

Because you probably do not change your set of Add-ons frequently, I would create a bookmark folder with favorite Add-ons rather than having them installed automatically. Then, after logging into Sync, your bookmarks will be synced, then you can use the bookmarked Addons to manually install the Add-ons you want for that specific machine.